# Telerik Grid ASP.NET MVC grid binding does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have used below code in View and Controller for Grid Binding:

### View:

```
@( Html.Telerik().Grid<MvcApplication1.Models.Movie>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .EnableCustomBinding(true)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(m => m.Title).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(m =>m.Director).Width(200);
                columns.Bound(m => m.DateReleased).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);

            })
            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_AjaxBinding", "Home"))
    )
```

### Controller:

```
[GridAction]
        public ActionResult _AjaxBinding()
        {
            return View(new GridModel<Movie> { Data = GetMovies() }); }

        private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
        {
            return _db.Movie.ToList();
        }
```

But the problem is it is never reaching _AjaxBinding Grid Action.

Please let me know am i missing any web.config changes related to Telerik control.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if you have a ScriptRegistrar in your page. Also check the online demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custombinding

Answer (score 0):

Since you have custom binding enabled, you need to set `EnableCustomBinding` of the `GridActionAttribute` attribute of your action method to `true`.

```
[GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
public ActionResult _AjaxBinding(GridCommand command) {
    // ...
}
```

See [Custom Ajax Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/custombinding).

---

But judging from the simplicity of your view and controller, it doesn't look like you need custom binding.

See simple [Ajax Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/ajaxbinding).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have set the EnableCustomBinding to true of the GridActionAttribute still it doesnot work.